# apply $pull on nested array object in MongoDB

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB object having an array which is further having nested arrays

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a7d4e16c8e12b396b0efe0b"),
"UserName" : "person",
"ParentArray" : [ 
    {
        "ModuleID" : "1112",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7d4e16c8e12b396b0efe17"),
        "ChildArray" : [      {
                "ChildCount" : "0000",
                "name" : "One",
            }
      ],
    }, 
    {
        "ModuleID" : "1113",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7d4e16c8e12b396b0efe15"),
        "ChildArray" : [ 
            {
                "ChildCount" : "0001",
                "name" : "two",
            },
{
                "ChildCount" : "0011",
                "name" : "two point two",
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "ModuleID" : "0002",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7d4e16c8e12b396b0efe13"),
        "ChildArray" : [ 
            {
                "ChildCount" : "0002",
                "name" : "three",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a7d4e16c8e12b396b0efe14")
            }
    ,
    {
                "ChildCount" : "0011",
                "name" : "two point two",
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete a selected object inside ChildArray for instance I want to delete an object having "ChildCount" : 0011 , "name":"two point two"

I only got the solution in deleting doubly nested arrays which was with the following code `{$pull:{"ParentArray.0.ChildArray":{ChildCount:"0000"}}`

I couldn't find any documentation on how to apply `$pull` in this situation